# Where can I find seasons 2 and 3 of "You're Under Arrest"

Tags: youre-under-arrest

I just finished the 52 episodes of You're Under Arrest on watchcartoononline. But, I can not find any episodes of You're Under Arrest 2 or 2001 and I haven't checked Full Throttle just in case the universe is trying to torture me.

Can anyone help me with links?

Note, I am stupid and only know the English language. I say this because in my search for another episode, I found one in Korean dub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Anime News Network, [*You're Under Arrest: Second Season*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=621) and [*You're Under Arrest: You're Under Arrest: Full Throttle*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=8152) are streamable from Anime News Network and Hulu.

However, I have never been able to find the Anime News Network Stream Links and when you look for [*You're Under Arrest* on Hulu](https://www.hulu.com/youre-under-arrest) it says "Currently Unavailable" with the Google result saying:

> You're Under Arrest is currently unavailable to stream on-demand, but may be available on Hulu with Live TV depending on regional availability. Try Live TV for free.

This could be because of paywall or geoblocking on Australia.

However, you can pick up the complete collections of [Second Season](https://www.rightstufanime.com/Youre-Under-Arrest-Season-2-DVD-Complete-Collection-S) and [Full Throttle](https://www.rightstufanime.com/Youre-Under-Arrest-Full-Throttle-DVD-Complete-Collection-S) on DVD from Rightstuff.

It should be pointed out that Second Season and Full Throttle are subbed only as Anime News Network has no **English cast** list unlike [the first season](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=620).